# Creating custom StackController in dojo

Tags: dojo

I want navigate on different ContentPane using custom link, which is there on the left side in the Table (i.e. Screen x.x), how can I do this instead of using the default StackController.

Kindly help me as I am new with this dojo, thanks in advance.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <table border='1' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'>
        <tr><th>Category 1</th><td>Screen 1.1</td></tr>

        <tr><th rowspan='3'>Category 2</th><td>Screen 2.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Screen 2.2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Screen 2.3</td></tr>

        <tr><th rowspan='2'>Category 3</th><td>Screen 3.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Screen 3.2</td></tr>            
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.StackController" data-dojo-props="containerId:'stackContainer'"></div> 
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.StackContainer" id="stackContainer">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='cnt_0101' title="Screen 1.1">
                Categor 1 - Screen 1.1
            </div>

            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='cnt_0201' title="Screen 2.1">
                Categor 2 - Screen 2.1
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='cnt_0202' title="Screen 2.2">
                Categor 2 - Screen 2.2
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='cnt_0203' title="Screen 2.3">
                Categor 2 - Screen 2.3
            </div>

            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='cnt_0301' title="Screen 3.1">
                Categor 3 - Screen 3.1
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='cnt_0302' title="Screen 3.2">
                Categor 3 - Screen 3.2
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Hi everyone,

I want navigate on different ContentPane using custom link, which is there on the left side in the Table (i.e. Screen x.x), how can I do this instead of using the default StackController.

Kindly help me as I am new with this dojo, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function navigateTo(divContainer)
{
    this.dijit.byId('stackContainer').selectChild(divContainer)
}
</script>
```

**selectChild()** is the method which can be use to navigate to different container in Stack Container layout.